# XSLT - how to remove certain elements from XML structure

Tags: xml, xslt

Am new to the world of XSLT and am facing issues with how to go about it
I have following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<Output>
    <Error>
        <Status>0</Status>
        <Details>No errors</Details>
    </Error>
    <Synopsis>
        <Count>451</Count>
    </Synopsis>
    <BankAccounts>
        <BankAccount AcctNo="103" CustName="Frank" BalanceAmount="" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1" >
            <Addresses>
                <Address>ABC</Address>
                <Address>XYZ</Address>
            </Addresses>
        </BankAccount>
        <BankAccount AcctNo="101" CustName="Jane" BalanceAmount="10005" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1" >
            <Addresses>
                <Address>LMN</Address>
                <Address>QWE</Address>
            </Addresses>
        </BankAccount>
        
    </BankAccounts>
</Output>
```

I need to convert it to :

```
<BankAccounts>
    <BankAccount AcctNo="103" CustName="Frank" BalanceAmount="" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1" >
        <Addresses>
            <Address>ABC</Address>
            <Address>XYZ</Address>
        </Addresses>
    </BankAccount>
    <BankAccount AcctNo="101" CustName="Jane" BalanceAmount="10005" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1" >
        <Addresses>
            <Address>LMN</Address>
            <Address>QWE</Address>
        </Addresses>
    </BankAccount>
    
</BankAccounts>
```

I tried applying following XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
     <!-- Identity template, copies everything as is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
    
    <xsl:template match="Output/Error">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>    
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I get the exception :

> net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 8; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: Whether you want to process XML with XSLT or otherwise, it has to be well-formed, one of the requirement is that there is no white space before the XML declaration, your document seems to have blanks before the XML declaration. The XML parser is telling you that is not allowed, or, rather, at this point of parsing, it expects an XML processing instruction, but one looking like an XML declaration, is not allowed. So you need to fix your input document.

Comment: Thanks - have corrected the document - will update the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve it based on the identity transformation e.g.

```
<!-- Identity template, copies everything as is -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

just add an empty template

```
<xsl:template match="Error | Synopsis"/>
```

to prevent copying those elements and make sure the root elements doesn't get copied but its child nodes get processed:

```
<xsl:template match="Output">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `xsl:copy-of ...` of the relevant element and mask the `text()` nodes which would be copied by the [Built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule) like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />
  
  <xsl:template match="/Output">
    <xsl:copy-of select="BankAccounts"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is as desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BankAccounts>
    <BankAccount AcctNo="103" CustName="Frank" BalanceAmount="" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1">
        <Addresses>
            <Address>ABC</Address>
            <Address>XYZ</Address>
        </Addresses>
    </BankAccount>
    <BankAccount AcctNo="101" CustName="Jane" BalanceAmount="10005" Inactive="N" NoOfAccounts="1">
        <Addresses>
            <Address>LMN</Address>
            <Address>QWE</Address>
        </Addresses>
    </BankAccount>
</BankAccounts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Output">
    <xsl:copy-of select="BankAccounts"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```